# Single marker not visualized using ngx leaflet markercluster

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

When I zoom in a cluster on a map, using ngx angular version of leaflet-markercluster, I can't visualize single marker.

Different result can be obtained using pure javascript and js-version of above modules.

The code of map.component is below:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';

@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    templateUrl: './map.component.html'
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() coords:number[][];
    options = {
        zoom: 5,
    maxZoom : 18,
        center: L.latLng([ 41.5, 12.5 ]),

   layers: [L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {})],


    };

    // Marker cluster stuff
  markerClusterGroup: L.MarkerClusterGroup;
    markerClusterData: L.Marker[] = [];
    markerClusterOptions: L.MarkerClusterGroupOptions;


    ngOnInit() {

        this.markerClusterData = this.generateMarker(this.coords);
    }

    markerClusterReady(group: L.MarkerClusterGroup) {
        this.markerClusterGroup = group;
    }
   [...]
```

Leaflet options are defined in

```html
    <div leaflet style="height: 400px;"
        [leafletOptions]="options"
        [leafletMarkerCluster]="markerClusterData"
        [leafletMarkerClusterOptions]="markerClusterOptions"
        (leafletMarkerClusterReady)="markerClusterReady($event)">
    </div>
```

You can visualize entire code and run on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-ts)

How can I resolve single marker visualization?

Comment: Does it work without Leaflet.markercluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the well known bundle issue with webpack. 
Define the `iconUrl` inside the `icon` variable and it should fix the problem.

```
const icon = L.icon({
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [10, 41],
    popupAnchor: [2, -40],
    // specify the path here
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
    shadowUrl:
      "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
});
```

And just an advice, keep the iconUrl outside the for loop. As you need to declare the variable only once.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-ts-pp8thv)

Comment: wonderful! thank you! probably the problem was related to missing import of the png images!